# About resume broken upload with AsiHttpRequest

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

I use ASIFormDataRequest to upload my file to Server.
But when the wireless signal is not good enough, Uploading is always failed in the end.
How can I do to resume broken upload? Do AsiHttpRequest support it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

HTTP in general doesn't support resuming uploads.

I think your best approach would be to change the way you upload the file, so that you upload it in chunks.

ie. split the file down into segments of a smaller size (eg. 256 kilobytes) and send each of them in a separate ASIFormDataRequest. Then get your server software to glue them back together.